# why my console.log(req.body) give: {} in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to update a post in my bdd with the new value. When i click for validate i have an empty req.body!

```js
exports.updatePost = (req, res, next) => {

    Post.update(
      {
        message: req.body.message,
      },
      { where: { id: req.params.id } }
    )
    .then(() => res.status(200).json({ message: "post modifié" }))
    .catch((error) => res.status(500).json({ error }));
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.params.id)
};
```

As you can see i console log my req.body for check, my req.paramas.id give me the right thing. Since i have this problem i decided to check my post route and my app.js but i didn't see anything.

my route is like this:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const postCtrl = require("../controllers/post");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const multer = require("../middleware/multer-configs");

//DIFFERENTE ROUTES POUR LES POSTS, COMPRENNANTS LES DIFFERENTS MIDDLEWARE UTILES ET D'AUTHENTIFICATION
router.get("/", auth, postCtrl.getAllPost);
router.post("/", auth, multer, postCtrl.createPost);
router.delete("/:id", auth, postCtrl.deletePost);
router.put("/:id", auth, postCtrl.updatePost);
router.get("/:id", auth, postCtrl.getPostByUserId);

module.exports = router;
```

and my app.js is like this:

```js
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("./models");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const postRoutes = require("./routes/post");
const likeRoutes = require("./routes/like");
const commentRoutes = require("./routes/comment");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//MODULE C.O.R.S
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// POST
app.use("/api/post", postRoutes);
```

I don't really understand why my backend can't see the back or don't give me the result of my body.

my client side is like this actually:

```js
    const updatePost = () => {
       if (textEdit) {
           const data = new FormData();
              data.append("message", textEdit);


           axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/post/${id}`, data, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("authToken")}`,
                },
           })
           .then((res) => {

            console.log(res);
            console.log(id)
            console.log(message)
            console.log(textEdit)

           })

       }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use both `body-parser` and Express middlewares. Just use `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`. You do not need `body-parser` at all these days

Comment: How are you making the request from the client-side?

Comment: Are you sure you removed `body-parser`? It's still in the code above. Make sure you restart your server after removing it too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User validation works using Postman, fails on client using FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72526242/283366). **TL;DR** - don't use `FormData`, just use `const data = { message: textEdit };`